# Is laravel env file more powerful than config files?

Tags: php, laravel

The main first file to edit while configuring new Laravel project is usually `.env` file. It contains all the basic configurations that I need.

However, the `config` directory contains much more data but some of it is just duplicated.

While some lines in `config` directory files say *"please set it in env file"*, the documentation says *"All of the configuration files for the Laravel framework are stored in the config directory"*.

Now my question is - what place should contain my configuration information? Is any of these on the top of another? Is any of them more powerful?

Comment: Configuration files _can_ read `.env` information. `.env` files are for a specific environment (local,staging,production), so you don't have to adjust your config files. What exactly is duplicated in config files?

Answer (score 1):

.env file for manage your environment such as production, development..

config key firstly loop up env file if key not present, uses default value

Such as:

```
'name' => env('APP_NAME', 'Laravel'),
```

.env file should be in your .gitignore file. So in your localhost you can use localhost credentials and in your server you can use production credentials.